# Configuring HTTPS redirect fails

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, hosting

I am hosting a Django application on `digitalocean`. I follow [this tutorial](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9419/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx) to finish its SSL certification. Following that tutorial I don't know where to add this line of code:

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

I tried adding it in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/leptitox_pro`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 68.183.203.33 yahkut.com www.yahkut.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/leptitoxadmin/pyapps/Leptitox;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/leptitoxadmin/pyapps/Leptitox;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

when it didn't work I added it in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/leptitox_pro`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 68.183.203.33 yahkut.com www.yahkut.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/leptitoxadmin/pyapps/Leptitox;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/leptitoxadmin/pyapps/Leptitox;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

it didn't work there as well, so I added below the server block of code in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        server {                                           # new
          listen 80;                                       # new
          server_name yahkut.com;                          # new
          return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;     # new
        }

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
}
```

I then restarted ngnix and run `nginx -t` and got a success message, and when I ran the website I get either `404 not found` or Not secure version of the website.
Please help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to seperate the server block running port 80 and the server block running port 443 (SSL). Just like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 68.183.203.33 yahkut.com www.yahkut.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    # Stop here, it's will be redirect to HTTPS. There's no left to execute
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name yahkut.com www.yahkut.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate/your_domain_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your_private.key;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/leptitoxadmin/pyapps/Leptitox;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/leptitoxadmin/pyapps/Leptitox;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do I have to add these blocks of code? nginx.conf

Comment: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/leptitox_pro` is fine

Comment: `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "yahkut.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored` I get this error when restarting nginx

Comment: Delete all of your other code of yahkut.com on other files first.

Answer (score 0):

Add these server blocks.

This is to redirect http to https

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com; 
   location / {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
}
```

Your main block with ssl

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl ;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;  
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com; 
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5003; // Your port goes here
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

This goes under /nginx/sites-enabled/default or you can create different files for it in this folder